# Play morphia @Reference and abstract class relationship

Tags: playframework, morphia

I didn't find any answers about this particular "problem".
I am currently using Play framework 1.2.5 with Play Morphia module 1.2.9

Ok so here is the problem :
I have one class A which is abstract (not an @Entity because it's not allowed)
and two classes B and C that inherits from class A which extends from Model class.
Classes B and C have @Entity annotation.

I wanted to know if it is possible, for example in a fourth class, class D, to have a reference to A class ?
Actually I just want to use polymorphic behavior, I need to access a property defined in class A without knowing in advance if it is an instance of class B or C, but I need to retrieve these objects from the database anyway with the findById() method.

I don't know if it is really clear, but in the end my goal would be to execute findById() on the "class A object", and retrieve either an instance of a class B or C automatically.

Could you help me please ? (Maybe if I set the same collection on B and C with @Entity(value="xxxx") )

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute findById() on the "class A object" because MongoDB creates IDs only to objects which declared with the @Entity annotation.